# How can I make a DataFrame from a ColumnTransformer composed by LOO Encoder, OHE and Ordinal Encoder?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

Since the feature `get_feature_names()` was deprecated from "native" categorical encoders in Sklearn (actually it was replaced by `get_feature_names_out()`), how could I make a DataFrame where the transformed variables have their proper names since inside the ColumnTransformer has encoders whose respond for `get_feature_names_out()` and others for `get_feature_names()`? Here is the situation:

```
features_pipe = make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore', sparse=False), ['Gender', 'Race']),
    (OrdinalEncoder(), ['Age', 'Overall Work Exp.', 'Fieldwork Exp.', 'Level of Education']),
    (ce.LeaveOneOutEncoder(), ['State (US)'])
                                        ).fit(X_train, y_train)

X_train_encoded = features_pipe.transform(X_train)
X_test_encoded = features_pipe.transform(X_test)

X_train_encoded_df = pd.DataFrame(X_train_encoded, columns= features_pipe.get_features_names_out())
X_train_encoded_df.head()
I got this error: AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_features_names_out'
```

That's because LeaveOneOutEncoder does not support `get_feature_names_out()`. It supports `get_feature_names()`.

How could I overcome this issue and print my DataFrame correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue once in the past.

If you don't mind using a subclass of ColumnTransformer you can create it and just modify to call `get_feature_names()` when `get_feature_names_out()` was not available.

In this case, you should declare the class

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose._column_transformer import _is_empty_column_selection

class MyColumnTransformer(ColumnTransformer):
    def __init__(self, transformers, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(transformers=transformers, **kwargs)
        
    def _get_feature_name_out_for_transformer(
        self, name, trans, column, feature_names_in
    ):
        column_indices = self._transformer_to_input_indices[name]
        names = feature_names_in[column_indices]
        if trans == "drop" or _is_empty_column_selection(column):
            return
        elif trans == "passthrough":
            return names

        if not hasattr(trans, "get_feature_names_out"):
            return trans.get_feature_names()
        return trans.get_feature_names_out(names)
```

Although the use of `ColumnTransformer` is not as simple as using `make_column_transformer`, it's much more customizable.

So, in this case, you also have to pass a name to each transformer using the following schema:

*(name, transformer, columns)*

```
features_pipe = MyColumnTransformer(transformers=
    [
      ('OHE', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore', sparse=False), ['Gender', 'Race']),
      ('OE', OrdinalEncoder(), ['Age', 'Overall Work Exp.', 'Fieldwork Exp.', 'Level of Education']),
      ('LOOE', ce.LeaveOneOutEncoder(), ['State (US)'])
    ])
features_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and finally continue the code the way you suggested.

If you don't want to append the transformer names to the features names, just include `verbose_feature_names_out=False` when initializing `MyColumnTransformer`.